# Shear (Skew) transformation along arbitrary direction in 2d

Tags: math, transform, transformation, skew

I need to skew a 2d polygon shape in arbitrary direction (2d). Doing it in X axis looks like this:

```
   float skewAngle;
   glm::mat4 skewMatrix;
   skewMatrix[1][0] =  glm::tan(glm::radians(skewAngle));
```

Y-axis:

```
   skewMatrix[0][1] =  glm::tan(glm::radians(skewAngle));
```

I need to skew in both X and Y direction at the same time,where the direction is given by an angle between 0 - 360 (-+). In some graphics programs it is also called  "Skew Axis". I was trying something like this:

Let's say I want to skew the shape in direction given by 160 degrees.(zero degrees - shearing along X axis)

```
    float skewAxisAngle = 160.0f;  
    float skewAngle = glm::radians(skewAxisAngle);
```

Then I rotate my unit direction vector,which faces x-axis by default, with skewAngle.
        glm::vec2 rotatedDirection =  (glm::rotate(glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f), skewAngle));

Normalize   to stay always in range [0-1]:

```
    rotatedDirection =  glm::normalize(rotatedDirection ) ;
```

Then I applied the direction as weight component wise to X and Y skews:

```
 skewMatrix[1][0] = rotatedDirection.x * glm::tan(glm::radians(skewAngle));

 skewMatrix[0][1] = rotatedDirection.y * glm::tan(glm::radians(skewAngle));
```

The result seems to be working,but only for square angles.For angles like the above,the result looks wrong. My frame of reference is Adobe After Effects.

Correct:

[image]

Wrong:

[image]

Comment: The mathematical convention is to represent a 2D vector as a column, where the upper element is X and the lower one is Y. You seem to have those reversed; if that's all right with you, then we can proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your needs right, then look at the formula below from the book *(Nikulin Computer Geometry...)*.
It describes complex transformation of skew along axis `(o,V)` - base point and direction vector. T is translation matrix, R with tilda - rotation matrix.

[image: img]